# convert depth map (resulting from photometric stereo) to 3d mesh

Tags: python-2.7, computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction

I'm woking on project regarding 3d reconstruction. I obtained my depth map from photometric stereo method. Now, what I want to do, is convert the depth map to 3d mesh that i can visualise on meshlab for example. 
Can anyone tell me how can i do that ? 
PS : i'm working with python ! 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not a trivial exercise but is doable. The basic steps are:

- Use your dense depth map to generate a voxel representation
- Construct an IsoSurface for the voxel model using e.g. Marching Cubes algorithm

Take a look at this paper for one possible approach though it's far from the best way to do this: https://www.academia.edu/6148442/3D_Reconstruction_on_a_Mobile_Device in particular pp43-45 onwards

(Disclosure: It's my MRes thesis).